# Set ajax success callback as input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to set the data that is returned from the success callback in an AJAX request as an input value. This is not working. I have the feeling this is because I am using an AJAX request within an (.on) event function. I need to use the event function within the AJAX request ($this) to find the input I want to update.

```
$(function () {
        $("table").on('change', '.master', function () {
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", async: false, url: '<?php echo site_url('wordsuggestion'); ?>/hoi/nederlands/frans', success: function(data) { 
                $(this).parents('tr').find(".slave").val(data);
            }});
        });
    });
```

This is the form I'm using.

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="master" name="or[0]"></div>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="slave" name="tr[0]"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

It is a mystery for me why this is not working. I think that within the AJAX call, the $(this) operator can't be used any more which causes the input not to be updated.

Comment: In what way does this actually fail?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Are there any errors?

Comment: @David The AJAX request is definitely made now. The server responds with the content on that page, which is in this case a 7-letter word. No errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` doesn't refer to what you think in the AJAX callback.  The context of that callback is outside of the context of the original `change` event handler, which has already completed.

You can set the context in the `$.ajax()` call, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    type: "POST",
    // etc...
```

Or even just set the value to a variable and capture that variable for the callback:

```
var element = this;
$.ajax({
    success: function (data) {
        $(element).parents('tr')....
    },
    // etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).parents('tr').find(".slave").eq(0)
```